# How to use the Limit Comparison Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find if the series absolutely/conditionally diverges/converges on this problem,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{3^n}{n!}$

The absolute series of this is,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}$

Trying to find if the absolute series converges/diverges I used the Limit Comparison Theorem. I thought it could be comparable to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ because of the factorial, but I got a non-real answer. What should I use to compare to the series?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Leibniz's theorem for series. Note that for $n>2$

\begin{align*}
\frac{3^n}{n!}
\end{align*}

is a decreasing sequence that tends to $0$.